# Maven plugin in Eclipse Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I installed the maven plugin m2e for eclipse. 
Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

i tried many solutions in eclipse indigo but did not work for me. There is no settings.xml file. I manually created and tried to edit the proxy settings. I  have separate maven plugin installation. Please someone could help resolving the problem? Thank you very much.

Settings.xml:

[image]
.plugin folder structure:

[image]

Errors:

```
!SESSION 2016-08-05 08:05:16.128 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2016-08-05 08:16:30.768
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is set to 172.16.0.9 but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2016-08-05 08:16:30.783
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is set to 8080 but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2016-08-05 08:16:36.130
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is set to 172.16.0.9 but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2016-08-05 08:16:36.131
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is set to 8080 but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2016-08-05 08:16:36.142
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is set to 172.16.0.9 but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2016-08-05 08:16:36.143
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is set to 8080 but should not be set.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:47.894
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:57.900
!MESSAGE AsyncHttpClient.close() hasn't been invoked, which may produce file descriptor leaks

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:57.901
!MESSAGE AsyncHttpClient.close() hasn't been invoked, which may produce file descriptor leaks

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:57.902
!MESSAGE AsyncHttpClient.close() hasn't been invoked, which may produce file descriptor leaks

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:57.902
!MESSAGE AsyncHttpClient.close() hasn't been invoked, which may produce file descriptor leaks

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:57.903
!MESSAGE AsyncHttpClient.close() hasn't been invoked, which may produce file descriptor leaks

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:57.903
!MESSAGE AsyncHttpClient.close() hasn't been invoked, which may produce file descriptor leaks

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:19:57.904
!MESSAGE AsyncHttpClient.close() hasn't been invoked, which may produce file descriptor leaks

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2016-08-05 08:20:23.211
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-08-05 08:23:20.101
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2016-08-05 08:23:20.832
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.IndexUpdaterJob

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2016-08-05 08:23:21.171
!MESSAGE Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
!SESSION 2016-08-05 08:23:49.999 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-08-05 08:27:39.836
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2016-08-05 08:27:39.920
!MESSAGE Can't write workspace state

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2016-08-05 08:27:40.571
!MESSAGE Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
!SESSION 2016-08-05 08:27:41.724 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-08-05 08:29:06.544
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2016-08-05 08:29:07.516
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.IndexUpdaterJob
!SESSION 2016-08-05 08:29:07.960 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-08-05 08:38:15.731
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2016-08-05 08:38:16.709
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.repository.RepositoryRegistryUpdateJob

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2016-08-05 08:38:16.710
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.IndexUpdaterJob
!SESSION 2016-08-05 08:38:17.176 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-08-05 09:22:02.863
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2016-08-05 09:22:03.842
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.IndexUpdaterJob
```

**UPDATE**

i installed m2e plugin using eclipse.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a special reasons you still use Indigo? I would recommend Mars-2 or Neon.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to point your your local maven installation in eclipse, go preference > Maven > installations and in right hand panel 'add'

[image]

Then point your settings.xml in Maven > usersettings. Update settings

[image]

Comment: i have updated my question i have installed in eclipse not from external location . what should i do in that case.

Comment: point your local maven installation via 'add' installation, then as above point your user settings as well

Comment: where should i point to .m2 folder because i installed it  in eclipse from Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo using install new software options as i mentioned in update then what should be local repository for maven plugin.

Comment: You dont need to, your setting.xml have the .m2 folder (or any other folder which you may have pointed for the repo). Eclipse should automatically pickup everything for configuration such as above